# Update Fragment on ActionBar button Click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager with Tabbed Swipe Views and a "refresh" button sitting in the action bar. What I want to be able to do is re-create each tab fragment when the user clicks the refresh button:

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch(i) {
        case 0:
            return new F1();
        case 1:
            return new F2();
        case 2:
            return new F3();
        case 3: 
            return new F4();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4; //# tabs
    }
}
```

MainActivity onOptionsItemSelected

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_help:
                makeDialog();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Refreshing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //code to refresh fragments in here
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have not told us what you are trying to refresh, what is on each fragment, because you are not going to 'refresh' the entire fragment, just the data within it. SO for example calling an AsyncTask again and adding the new data to the current stuff showing.

Comment: Why you don't iterate over the `ViewPager` child's (visible and cached  `Fragments`) and refresh the `View` elements? Another option is to reset the `Adapter` (using `setAdapter` again), but it will force to destroy and recreate the `Fragment's` again.

Comment: Why not create an abstract base class that each of your Fragments inherits from with an abstract method refresh() that each would implement, then easily tell the ViewPager to call the currently-viewed child Fragment's refresh() method and handle everything from there instead of "re-creating" the Fragment?